# How I get values of url of tag image of size attribute?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, last.fm

How do I get the values of the url of a tag image of a mega attribute?

Should I get it by attribute?

How do I do this in PHP?

```
$string = file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getTopAlbums&artist=enya&lang=pt&autocorrect=1&api_key=1d07ae6d0a77914229c0ccaa75867fdf"); 

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

$cover = $xml->topalbums->album->image["size"]['extralarge'];

var_dump($cover);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your output of $string and have you examined the output of just $xml ?

Comment: This looks a bit strange `&lang=pt&=1&api_key` specifically `&=1&`.

Comment: Try `$cover = (string)$xml->topalbums->album->image;`